# EJB - Unexpected exception was found while rethrowing pending exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I get a strange exception when I invoke a method from an EJB.
The method of the EJB just consults to BD and returns a VO.
All works well when I invoke the method from a standalone client but, when I make the invocation from the same server, from another EJB, it returns:
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: Unexpected exception was found while rethrowing pending exception: (.VOObject) vmcid: IBM  minor code: EA5 completed: Maybe

The server is WebSphere Application Server 8.5, the EJB source is 3.1 and the EJB target is 2.1.

Ideas, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Make sure the VO class is in your caller EJB classpath (if you use Maven, add the corresponding dependency). Most likely the target EJB contains a method with that VO in its signature.

Comment: Indeed!, another method in the same EJB had an object in the signature that was not in my classpath. Thanks a lot for your help!